# Remove google play protect

Tags: android

My app has been released on Google Play Market
In other markets
Published with the same package name[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo9Ko.jpg) and the same key
But I get a Google Protect message
please guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Protect is on by default, but you can turn it off.

1. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
2. At the top right, tap
   the profile icon.
3. Tap Play Protect and then Settings.
4. Turn Scan apps
   with Play Protect on or off.